# can I use Bootstrap in a flask app with css and js files?

Tags: python, html, flask, bootstrap-4

This is my first time building a web page/web app so I don't have a strong understanding of project structure and terminology.

I have created a front end webpage using bootstrap along with some jquery. Now I want to use flask to utilize a python library and deploy it as a web app.

My question is in order to use bootstrap can I move my bootstrap CSS and js files from my website folder to my flask project, or do I have to use the python package flask-bootstrap?

What is the benefit of using the flask-bootstrap package vs using css/js files?

Thanks.

Comment: If this is your first time, consider spending a bit of time with https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world" , which sets up an example app that uses bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will work just copy the files to `static` folder in the main app directory(Make the folder if it doesn't exist). Change the source of the your files in html code. An example below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.min.css') }}" >
```